# Java applet jnlp deployment giving NoClassDefFoundError and wrong name error

Tags: java, deployment, applet, jnlp, noclassdeffounderror

I'm going to be honest and say that I have never deployed an applet, but it seems to be incredibly painful.  The `<applet code>` doesn't work on chrome so im using the jnlp to hopefully get past this nightmare, but it only seems to add to my migrane.  Everything runs fine in eclipse, but when it comes to deployment.. I might be needing a new computer if I can't figure this out haha.

Started out creating the java jar (jar cvf WebGame.jar bin):
[image]

Then I created the JNLP file that looks like this (named bounce.jnlp):
[image]

I thought I was starting to get somewhere when I created my html file (Bounce.html):
[image]

So I decided to upload everything to test out how it works on chrome:
[image]

It looked like my game was loading on the browser but I ended up getting this:
[image]

So after messing around with it for a couple of hours I'm all like this:

If anyone could help me out I would DEFINITELY appreciate it, (I can't really afford to buy a new computer at the moment).

Comment: 1) All 4 of those images would be better replaced with the copy/pasted text of the editor, command line or console. 2) The JNLP is invalid.  Be sure to check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `StartingPoint` class is not actually in the `bin` package, this is the hint for me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundException: bin/StartingPoint (wrong name StartingPoint)
```

This would indicate that your class is in the `default` package (i.e. has no package declaration at the beginning).

Try changing your JNLP to

```
main-class="StartingPoint"
```

and create your jar file from within the `bin` directory:

```
$ cd Documents/Java/TheBasics/WebGame/bin
$ jar cvf ../WebGame.jar *
```

Comment: You do not know how much in love with you I am right now!  Thank you so much beny23!  I don't know if you could/want to help me with this issue now though.  The applet is up and running, but it doesn't have my images (located in bin/images/*) and my music isn't being recognized either (bin/music/*).  Is that a problem with the way I have deployed my applet or something else entirely?  Any help would be appreciated, but you have already help me heeps, so thanks again!

Comment: I suspect that you'll need to change your code to load the images from `images/*` and `music/*`, as there now will be no entries with the `bin` directory in your code.